# Unable to view list in quick launch

Tags: list

I created an empty sharepoint project. Then I added a new application page and in the `page_load` method of the page I wrote this code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SPSite sitecollection = SPContext.Current.Site;

        SPWeb web = /*sitecollection.OpenWeb()*/ SPContext.Current.Web;

                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPListCollection lists = web.Lists;
                lists.Add("My new List", "A new list created using code", web.ListTemplates["Calendar"]);

                SPList newOne = web.Lists["My new List"];

                newOne.OnQuickLaunch = true;
                newOne.Fields.Add("Demofield", SPFieldType.Text, false);
                newOne.Update();
    }
```

And if I am right a new list will be created on the quick launch bar, but its not happening so. Did I miss something????

Comment: Do you see the new list? Use dispose your SPSite and SPWeb properly. They are deadly!

Comment: Hello Shoban. Thank you for the reply. And how to use the SPSite and SPWeb??? I am really new to shaepoint programming, please explain. Thank You

Comment: Check this post. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248%28v=office.12%29.aspx Also what happens when you execute the above code? Do you see the new list?

Comment: Hello, No I don't see the list in the quick launch and not even in "View All Site Content"

Comment: I modified the code which I am editing above. Please have a look and provide the feedback. Thanks

Comment: I am yet to test the above code. First look! it looks okay. How did you test? Do you see anythingin logs? no errors?

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again differently?

Comment: Because I still didn't get the answer. I am able to create a list using console application but if I do it with application page I m unable to do so. Did u try creating a list using application page???

Comment: Did you check the logs like I told you?

Comment: Please do not re-ask questions. Instead you should build up reputation so you can offer a bounty on your question to attract more answers.

Comment: Hello Shoban, I did check the logs but there are no errors. Please test the application at your end. I also added the <SafeControls> in web.config file and copied the .dll file as well. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are disposing an instance of SPContext.Current.Site (ie: enveloped it in a Using Statement). This is bad, as the SPSite will be disposed before the page has finished with it.

If you are getting an SPSite from SPContext, do not wrap it in a using statement.

Comment: Hello James, I modified the code accordingly, but no results. Please suggest

Comment: Is this a publishing site?

Comment: No, its a blank site.

Comment: Ok, I just tried this code and it worked for me, showed on the QuickLaunch and all (apologies for lack of formatting here) `SPSite site = new SPSite("http://demolab-sps2010");

            SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();

            Guid listG = web.Lists.Add("My List", "", web.ListTemplates["Calendar"]);
            SPList list = web.Lists[listG];

            list.OnQuickLaunch = true;
            list.Update();`

Comment: Hello James, thanks for the input but it didn't work for me. Where exactly are you writing that piece of code. Well I am creating an empty sharepoint project then added an application page and in the page_load method I am writing the above code. Is that right??? Please suggest

Comment: I had this in a console application with nothing else. This sounds silly, but are you sure you're deleting the list from the Site between trying to reload your Application Page?

Comment: hahha....no James I am not doing any such thing...well if its not too much to ask of you could you please create the list using the application page??? I'll try using the console application as you suggested. Thanks....

Comment: Hello James, it is working fine when using the console application but its not working when I use the application page. Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: If you create the list in your application page, and you navigation to another part of your site, do you see the list in the quick launch? I wonder if it's a timing issue...

Comment: Hmmm.....No, there is no such timing issue. Just to confirm I also navigated to other pages and I did not see the link on quick launch bar. I wonder if the same code works using Console Application, wht's wrong by using application page. Did you try the code in application page and did it work for u??? Just out of curiosity do I need to activate anything??

Answer (score 3):

If your code is excuted from an application page or web part:

```
SPContext.Current.Web.Lists.Add("My List Title", "Description of My List", SPListTemplateType.Announcements);
```

If your code is executed from a web-scoped feature, it will be in a feature receiver and you'll get the SPWeb from the properties parameter:

```
  using (SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb)
  {
    web.Lists.Add("My List Title", "Description of My List", SPListTemplateType.Announcements);
  }
```

Comment: Dear Laurie, thank you for the information. I have used the above mentioned code in an console application and it works, but however if I do it using an application page it doesn't work. Can you please provide me the steps on how to create a list using application page?? Thank you.

Comment: Some things to check: Verify that the user has permission to create a list on the site. Make sure that your dll is deployed to the GAC and that you have recycled the app pool for this web app. To be sure that your code is being executed, set a breakpoint and attach to the w3wp.exe process. Then execute the event that should hit your code.

Comment: Dear Laurie, I would like to add the information to the <SafeControls> tab in web.config file. So please suggest where I can find the information. I am using the application page only so how to obtain the info to add in <SafeControls> tab. Please suggest. thank u

Comment: SafeControl entry is not necessary for application pages. These pages reside on the file system and can execute code. The SafeControl entry is needed for web parts, since they will be added to a customized page and will reside in the database.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Google in your browser
2. Enter "sharepoint create list programmatically". Click Search.
3. Take your pick of the blog posts showing how to do this.

Comment: I could create list using console application in visual studio, but unable to do so using application page....if you can help me out please provide me the steps on how to do it....

Answer (score 1):

Check this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms425818.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I recommend getting a hold of this book: [Inside Microsoft SharePoint 2010](http://amzn.com/0735627460). It will provide you with a good foundation.

I used [Inside Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://amzn.com/0735623201) to learn SharePoint development, so I trust the 2010 version will be superb as well.

Without a good understanding of the framework, you are going to continue to be frustrated by the whole development experience.

Comment: Thank you Laurie. Just wanted to get my hands dirty while I learn coding. Cheers